# C++ Compare High Resolution Clock with fixed number

Tags: c++, emulation, c++-chrono

I'm working on an emulator and I don't understand how to compare elapsed time measured with the `chrono` library with the fixed number like (`CPUCycles * 0.0000005`).

Something like

```
auto lastTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
while (condition)
{
    if ((std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastTime) >= (CPUCycles * 0.0000005))
    {
        //do something;
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else;
    }
}
```

that at the moment give me the error

> Error C2676   binary '>=': 'std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::nano>'
>   does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to
>   the predefined operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastTime` returns a [`duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) hence you need to compare it to a duration. What this means depends on what your compared-to value means. The best/correct way is to convert that to a duration.

So your `CPUCycles * 500` returns the duration in nanoseconds? (`0.0000005 == 500e-9`) Then tell the compiler that:

```
if ((std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastTime) >= CPUCycles * std::chrono::nanoseconds(500))
```

See how clean this conveys the meaning? There is 1 cycle per 500ns -> So your time passed is CPUCycles times that.

The alternative is getting the count of a duration with the member function `count()` but you'll mostly want to cast the duration first:

```
auto diff = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastTime;
if(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff).count() >= CPUCycles * 500) ...
```

But this looses all the clarity the `chrono` gives you.

Comment: Many thanks, it works but I cant' figure out how it is possible that the condition is always true. Condition is fixed to 2MHz Intel 8080 speed versus my Intel core i3

Comment: are you setting `lastTime` in `//do something` to current time? If not that is your bug, otherwise we need more code (best in a separate question)

Comment: I found the problem. `cout` takes some time and print on video when condition is true and when is false is not possible. But if I alternately comment one `cout` I can see both of them

Answer (score 2):

The difference between two [`time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) object is a [`duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), which aren't readily convertible from any number. You have to explicitly construct a proper duration object.

There are a few standardized duration aliases, like `std::chrono::nanoseconds` which you can use as `std::chrono::nanoseconds(500)`:

```
if ((std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastTime) >= (CPUCycles * std::chrono::nanoseconds(500)))
```

Or if you use the `std::literals::chrono_literals` namespace you can use the "user" define literal `ns`:

```
if ((std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastTime) >= (CPUCycles * 500ns))
```